# Can Swift Scripts Execute in a Swift iOS App?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, obfuscation

We have an iOS app (Obj-C) that grabs a JavaScript file from AWS S3 to run our proprietary algorithm on a bunch of raw image data right on the iPhone (Lambda functions produced some latency I guess). For the sake of security, the JavaScript is obfuscated and entirely unreadable, and even harder to debug.

Well, the JavaScript is spitting out `NaN` result values back to the iPhone, and I am seriously struggling to even find where this `NaN` pollution starts. Very frustrating.

Behind the scenes I am working on refactoring this entire project to leverage Swift instead. It's much easier to dev/maintain than Objective-C (IMHO). Also, Swift can be used for scripting, so I'm thinking I can just reduce my tech stack by removing the JavaScript entirely.

**Question: Can a Swift script execute in a Swift iPhone app the same way JavaScript can? If yes, how?**

**The Objective-C code snippet (modified for brevity)**

```
functionCall = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"some JS function call"];
[jsContext evaluateScript: functionCall];
JSValue* jsv = [jsContext objectForKeyedSubscript: @"result"];
NSDictionary* result = [jsv toDictionary];
// result is != nil, but the values are all NaN
// Can't find the error when debugging JavaScript in Chrome
// C# utility app that does the same thing produces good results
```

I am aware that Apple will reject an app for the App Store if using an obfuscation tool on the source code is detected, or I'd consider purchasing a license for one. Also, we have an identical Android app, so if I can do the same with Kotlin scripts then I'll be a happy camper.

Another concern I have is if the obfuscated JavaScript code is even increasing the security. I understand that a jailbroken device can access device memory and get a hold of code at runtime, which makes me think I'm performing an exercise in futility. Phrased differently, is the obfuscated JavaScript effectively more secure than manually/primitively obfuscated Swift source code?

Comment: No, you won't be able to dynamically run a downloaded Swift script in your iOS app.

Comment: Damn. Do I have any alternatives to JavaScript then if I continue this pattern?

Comment: This seems like a strange architectural decision. Why not embed the algorithm in compiled Swift code in your application? Does it change frequently? At the very least when in development you should not be working with obfuscated code. Perhaps there's a way that you can point your app to the unprocessed source code of that JS while developing.

Comment: @AlexWayne, thank you for reaching out. Personally, I would love to just code the algorithm in Swift, but this is a management decision (one that I don't agree with for several reasons). I have since moved the script development to VS Code (solid debugging), and I'm using TypeScript to avoid typed issues like NaN pollution. So far this works.

Comment: Well good luck then :) In regards to your last question, obfuscated code is more secure than plain JS, but not by a lot. At the end of the day it's still interpreted code that must remain structurally similar to the source. Compiled byte code is _much_ more secure since it's much harder to reconstruct the original source from that. If security is the primary concern, then compiled Swift shipped with the app is going to be _much_ more secure than obfuscated JS downloaded from the internet that could be easily intercepted and analyzed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user jvnpdx stated, it is not possible to dynamically run a Swift script within the app.